# React, Redux, TypeError: undefined is not an object, if statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Ive tried several forum solutions but still stumped. Thanks for any help...

I am trying to display the number of total posts made by `user` by taking the most recent post's `postCount`.

My problem is when `user` hasn't posted anything yet and `this.props.user.myFeed[0].postCount`, the redux prop that holds user's posts/feed, hasn't been created yet. The screen tries to load and I get `"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.user.myFeed[0]')"`

Ive tried several solutions but is there a reason why the simple code below doesn't work.

`<Text>Posts: {(this.props.user.myFeed[0]) ? this.props.user.myFeed[0].postCount : 0 }</Text>`

Also have tried below:

`<Text>Posts: {(this.props.user.myFeed[0] === undefined) ? this.props.user.myFeed[0].postCount : 0 }</Text>`

If the store is undefined, shouldn't it simply be `0` ?

Thanks again!
-Matt

Comment: If the store is undefined, then it'll be just that… undefined. You can probably initialise the store to have some empty state so that you don't get the error, or check if this.props.user is defined before trying to access child keys.

Comment: By the way, ```myFeed``` is created as an empty array [] when the user is first created.  

In response to you, I thought thats what I was doing with the code above, checking to see if there is a most recent post ```myFeed[0]``` and then if it is undefined return ```0```; but if it is there, return its ```postCount``` prop.  Didn't I write it correctly to perform that check and see if its undefined?  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `myFeed` is an empty array, which means myFeed[0] is returning error. Therefore you should check the `myFeed` is not undefined to proceed. Also check postCount if possible.

```
    <Text>Posts: {(this.props.user.myFeed && this.props.user.myFeed[0]) ?
 this.props.user.myFeed[0].postCount : 0 }</Text>
```